# Org headlines are never exported to \paragraph in LaTeX

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

I want to export an Org file into PDF, with any depth titles showed in TOC; however, cannot works. Even though adding `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}`, TOC still only contains the title of 3rd depth (`\subsubsection`).

I check the TeX file it exported: org-export seemed to ignore my setting for `org-latex-classes`, and just convert `****` into `'\item` instead of `\paragraph`. But I cannot find some worked solution for this...

Following is my `org-latex-classes`:

```
(setq org-latex-classes
  '(("article"         "
\\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\\usepackage{fontspec}

\\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\\linespread{1.36}

\\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\\usepackage{multicol}

\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}
"
 ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
 ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
 ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
 ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
 ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
    )
  )
```

Comment: This isn't really about TOCs. It's about headlines not getting exported as paragraphs (there's a setting for that, the name eludes me now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
;; This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
;; then enter the text in that file's own buffer.

(let ((org-latex-classes
   '(("my-article" "
\\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\\usepackage{fontspec}

\\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\\linespread{1.36}

\\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\\usepackage{multicol}

\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}"
      ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
      ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
      ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
      ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
      ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))))
  (with-temp-buffer
(insert
 (mapconcat 'identity
        '("#+LATEX_CLASS: my-article"
          "#+OPTIONS: h:5 num:3"
          "* section"
          "** subsection"
          "*** subsubsection"
          "**** paragraph"
          "***** subparagraph")
        "\n"))
(org-latex-export-as-latex nil nil nil t)))
```

=>

```
\section{section}
\label{sec-1}
\subsection{subsection}
\label{sec-1-1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\label{sec-1-1-1}
\paragraph*{paragraph}
\label{unnumbered-1}
\subparagraph*{subparagraph}
\label{unnumbered-2}
```

For more info see http://orgmode.org/org.html#Export-settings.

Answer (score 3):

In org mode manual, [LaTeX-header-and-sectioning](https://orgmode.org/org.html#LaTeX-header-and-sectioning)

> The LaTeX export back-end converts the **first three** of Org’s outline
> levels into LaTeX headlines.  *The remaining Org levels are exported as
> lists.*  To change this globally for the cut-off point between levels and
> lists, (see note Export Settings).

In [Export-Settings](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Export-Settings), this is the setting to change the levels to be converted.

> H 
> Set the number of headline levels for export
> (‘org-export-headline-levels’).  Below that level, headlines are
> treated differently.  In most back-ends, they become list items.

so, you could add this at the beginning of your org file, so the 4th level to be exported would be (in your case) `\paragraph`

```
#+OPTIONS: H:5
```